# Resized frames from source gif add to new gif in Imagick PHP

Tags: php, imagick

I try to crop and then resized frames in gif to small resulotion - 160x160 and 200x200. But not all frame was cropped. Here's my code:

```
$dstImage->setImageFormat('gif');

$srcImage = $srcImage->coalesceImages();
$dstImage = $dstImage->coalesceImages();

    while ($srcImage->hasNextImage())
      {
      $srcImage->cropImage($srcImageW, $srcImageH, $srcImageX, $srcImageY);
      $srcImage->resizeImage($dstImageW, $dstImageH, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
      $dstImage->compositeImage($srcImage, Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, $dstImageX, $dstImageY);
      $dstImage->compositeImage($srcImage, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVERLAY, $dstImageX, $dstImageY);
      $dstImage->compositeImage($srcImage, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, $dstImageX, $dstImageY);
      $dstImage->addImage($srcImage);
      $dstImage->setImageDelay(10);

      $srcImage->nextImage();
      $dstImage->nextImage();
      }

    $srcImage = $srcImage->deconstructImages();
    $srcImage = $srcImage->deconstructImages();

    $dstImage->writeImages($osDstPath, true);
```

Comment: Seems like you're doing srcImage->nextImage() twice per iteration in your loop?

Comment: I fixed statement in while `$srcImage->hasNextImage()`. I did mistake when I copy code.